# Posting multiple objects in an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of data which is within multiple objects.

Each object has an ID and a status and then the main object has a type and a form id.

The problem I am having is posting result via ajax as it doesn't like the multiple objects.

This is the code I have:

```
var permissionsData = [];

$(".workflowBox").each(function(index, element) {

var obj = { 
status: $(this).attr("data-user-status"), 
record:$(this).attr("data-user-id")
};

permissionsData.push(obj); 
});

permissionsData.userGroupID = userGroupID;
permissionsData.formID = formID;

var posting =   $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.test.com",
        method: 'post', 
        data: permissionsData
});
```

How can I wrap/send permission data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about changing your array to an object and using jQuery's [param function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

```
var permissionsData = {};

$(".workflowBox").each(function(index, element) {

    var obj = { 
        status: $(this).attr("data-user-status"), 
        record:$(this).attr("data-user-id")
    };

    permissionsData[index] = obj; 
});

permissionsData.userGroupID = userGroupID;
permissionsData.formID = formID;

var posting =   $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.test.com",
    method: 'post', 
    data: $.param(permissionsData)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use json2.js
it can  parse the object to json string and parse the json string to object
you can use JSON.stringify method for parse object to  json string

Comment: i tried var test = JSON.stringify(permissionsData); and then passing that but that didnt work